# Enter parameter value to populate date time columns in sql

Tags: sql, vba, parameters, enter

I have a table with `datetime` column `Checkin`.

How to populate `Checkin` via "Enter parameter value" dialog box with SQL query?

Best regards

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking ... do you want to populate a table by using a SQL query which gets one of its parameters from a dialog box?

Comment: When type some date in dialog box to populate date time field in form

Comment: i will assume that means "no". ... you want to somehow open a dialog box, then you enter a date in the dialog box, press OK, then some field, in some form, gets filled with date and time.  .... is that correct?

Comment: Here is my sql code to check room booking availability.

Comment: I have my sql code in query to check room booking availability.On form I have button ,,check availability,, , on click open dialog  FIRST PARAMETER then SECON PARAMETER and put date1 and date2. It works perfect but after check availability every time I need again to popolate manuely date time field CheckIn and CheckOut in form witjh the same value as I put in FIRST PARAMETER and SECOND PARAMETER in bialog box. I would be great to automatic populate date time field in form when type in eg. FIRST PARAMETER .

Comment: when you enter the values in the first form, store the values in a table, then retrieve the values as many times as you like after that. name the table "scratchpad" or "temp" or something that means that it is a temporary data table to avoid confusion in the future. you could probably store other temporary data in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming in ms access, write a new query like this :

```
SELECT Checkin FROM yourtable where yourcolumn=?;
```

Comment: I need when type date in dialog box ..enter parameter value.. to automatic fill data in data time field in some form